# Angular UI-Router multiple Views without updating each

Tags: javascript, angularjs, routes, angular-ui-router

I am experiencing an issue with the Angular UI-Router Framework.
I have 2 nested views in another one and each time, I change to that "multi-view" View, both controllers I set to the sub-views are reloading there initial methods for both. So when I reload the page and both views are updated, they are both something like double-updated. This leads to the fact, that one of the controllers requests via $http twice some data. Each method I define in the controller will execute twice.

Is there any possibilty to prevent the updating for one of the views.
My current suggestion is, that each time a new view is loaded, all ui-views are compiled so it compiles twice for 2 views. :/

The Main HTML:

```
....
<div ui-view></div>
....
```

My sub-view is something like this:

```
...
<div ui-view="view1"></div>
<div ui-view="view2"></div>
...
```

My App state configuration:

```
....
.state('model', {
url:"/model/{modelId}",
controller: 'modelCtrl',
templateUrl: 'partials/model.html'
})
.state('model.Overall', {
views: {
  'view1': {
    templateUrl: 'partials/view1/view.html',
    controller: 'view1Ctrl'
  },
  'view2': {
    templateUrl: 'partials/views2/view.html',
    controller: 'view2Ctrl'
  }
}
})
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what each view is for but, if you need to have them both visible at the same time, you could try having the modelCtrl firing the method/function you need to happen on load instead of the subview controllers.

However, if these subviews are being toggled, you could set `'model'` to be an abstract state: `abstract: true` and have one ui-view `<ui-view="chewy"></ui-view>` (I always say chewy because it's kind of a chewy center?). So then you would have two substates:

```
.state('model.view1', {
 views: {
  'chewy': {
     templateUrl: 'partials/view1/view.html',
     controller: 'view1Ctrl'
   }
 }
 })
 .state('view2', {
 views: {
   'chewy': {
     templateUrl: 'partials/views2/view.html',
     controller: 'view2Ctrl'
    }
  }
 }) ...
```

Comment: Thank you for your Intention, this could work but I would prefer a method or way to keep those sub-controllers. For me its much more structured since those 2 states won't stay alone and I am going to add several different states / controllers there.